# Can't resolve '@angular/router/src/utils/collection'

Tags: angular

I'm trying to do a foreach and I have this error.

[Screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BYkNH.png)

[Screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nOzzF.png)

Comment: you do realise you should be able to simply do `this.data.forEach()`?

Comment: Please do not use images to convey textual information. [Edit] your question to replace them with the respective code. Additionally, questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Without this, your question is off-topic and liable to be closed. Please construct a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and include it.

Answer (score 5):

There is no need to import forEach, it's a basic JS method.

However, it's not a static method but a a member of the array prototype, therefore you need to call it on the array you want to operate on like this:

```
this.data.foreach(element => {
  doSomething();
});
```

... and please do us all a favour and do not post screenshots of code, instead paste well formatted code. People are far more likely to help you if you make it easy for them.

Answer (score 0):

try to import it only from `'@angular/router'`

.. hope it helps you!!

Comment: `forEach` is a javascript/typescript method. it is not an angular import